# How to add extra functionality to a compiled and hosted website in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, decompiler, precompiled

I have an ASP.NET 2.0 legacy website with me, in which I have to fix two bugs in the website.
The problem is that we ( me and client ) do not have the source code for this website.

All we have is the FTP where the compiled and hosted version of the website resides.
Now, we are pretty sure that the developer has not intentionally done anything to obfuscate that compiled code with any other third party tools. He have just used the standard Visual Studio compiler.

My questions are

1. Is it possible to get the source code from the compiled version?
2. How can I get the source code from this compiled version?
3. What other options do I have?
4. Will [.NET reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) be handy to extract the code?

Comment: That happens when you don't used source control system :)

Comment: @Ankur: I use TFS, mercurial.. but this is a *fix-it-legacy-app* that just came to me. :)

Comment: I can understand the position you are in right now because of someone else fault :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, .Net Reflector should be all you need to decompile the code (without comments, anyway).

Try opening the DLL files from the bin directory inside .Net Reflector and see if you can make sense of it.

**EDIT:** It appears that after investigating [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx), which Adrian Iftode mentioned, there is an open source plugin for .Net Reflector called [Reflexil](http://reflexil.net/) that does what you need - modifying compiled DLLs. That would be well worth a look at!

Comment: Not that I know of, but I am not sure how to extract the source code for all classes at once, though.

Comment: @AdrianIftode Thanks! I didn't event know ILSpy existed. Good to know there is an open source alternative being developed. Reading their Wiki page also lead me to discover Reflexil, which is a plugin for Reflector that appears to do what the OP wanted. Great teamwork!